# Polymer 2.0 - bootstrap classes are not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to use bootstrap CSS classes with polymer2.0 but it is working

HTML:

```
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/moment-js+saeidzebardast+0.7.2/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="moment-js/moment-js.html">
</head>

<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<polymer-header></polymer-header>

<dom-module id="polymer-header">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>



    <div class="navbar">
      [[result.header.name]]
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>



      <!-- navigation strip with descriptive text -->

  </template>


</dom-module>
```

JS:

```
/**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class PolymerHeader extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'polymer-header'; }
      static get properties() {
      return {};
    }


    }

    window.customElements.define(PolymerHeader.is, PolymerHeader);
```

Codepen-  https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BZwjqq

Didnt find much help online and finding results for polymer 1 and the closest i found is https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3156 but it was posted back in 2015.

I tried different options of link import but didnt help much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because when you make a `dom-module`, the dom that you create is a **shadow-dom**, that means outer manipulations and stylings are ineffective to these elements inside the dom.

If you really want to use bootstrap css classes (which I don't recommend, because Polymer already has good custom elements that will help to design your applications), try the following :

make a new html file called `bootstrap-classes.html` that contains :

```
<dom-module id="bootstrap-classes">
  <template>
    <style>
      <!-- copy paste all your bootstrap classes that you are interested in -->
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

now in your dom-module :

```
<link rel="import" href="bootstrap-classes.html"> <!-- include the style module -->
<dom-module id="polymer-header">
  <template>
    <style include="bootstrap-classes"> <!-- add the include -->
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>


    <!-- now the classes should work -->
    <div class="navbar">
      [[result.header.name]]
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>



      <!-- navigation strip with descriptive text -->

  </template>

  <script>
    ...
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: is there any way to import bootstrap css inside <style></style>  instead of complete bootstrap css

Comment: @NagaSaiA try using `<link rel="import" href="../path/to/bootstrap.css">` inside `<style></style>` but that's deprecated so it may not work. I don't know.

Comment: @NagaSaiA did you try to add `<link rel="import" href="../path/to/bootstrap.css">` outside `<style></style>` ? in `<template></template>` ?

Comment: @NagaSaiA or try to write `<link rel="import" type="css" href="../path/to/bootstrap.css">` in both cases.

Comment: Tried adding inside template outside style- <link rel="import" type="css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: Please check my updated codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BZwjqq

Comment: Thanks ballangddang , it works.. just one last question , for js to work , i need to use it same way like jquery and bootstrap.min.js

Comment: @NagaSaiA I am not sure to understand your last question. you mean how do you use JavaScript ? you should try to read some more polymer documentation if you ever happen to have no clue on that. If you include some scripts inside your document (or the <head> section) you'll be able to use the frameworks anywhere in your application (e.g. in your custom element definition).

Comment: Thanks ballangddang, my question was some of the bootstrap classes depend on jquery , is it required to define same way as bootstrap classes

Comment: @NagaSaiA no you don't need to do like bootstrap classes for scripts, scripts are window-scoped, that means you don't need to do some hacky stuff to have access to them from the shadow-doms. it's all good

Comment: Thanks @ballangddang