# Using Polymer 2.0 with Bootstrap JS

Tags: polymer, bootstrap-4

I need to use Polymer 2.0 (for creating Web components), and Bootstrap (as a framework for styling). 
I've created simple web component and added dropdown element into it:

```
<dom-module id="my-component">
  <template>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
      src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
      src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
          data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropTest">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyComponent extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-component' }

      constructor() {
        super();
      }
    }

    customElements.define(MyComponent.is, MyComponent);       
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

But, when I click on dropdown it is not working correctly.
I can see that Bootstrap's styles are being applied, but dropdown doesn't expand.

I think it could be because Polymer uses Shadow DOM, and Bootstrap JS cannot use it.

Maybe I am importing Bootstrap JS incorrectly?

Could anyone please clarify how to correctly use Polymer and Bootstrap together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polymer 2.0 - bootstrap classes are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743275/polymer-2-0-bootstrap-classes-are-not-working)

Comment: Including your scripts in the template of a dom-module object is wrong. Don't do that. just include the frameworks in the core of your document or in the `<head>` section.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. I did that: include js files to head section of index.html. But, it doesn't work.I see, I see that my dropdown is styled, but when I click on it, it doesn't expand.

Comment: Bootstrap CSS works. But my main problem is Bootstrap JS doesn't work. Is it possible to use Bootstrap JS with Polymer, despite on Shadow DOM?

Comment: You have to create an import file for those js files. Create a new html file call it bootrap-import.html within this you place your script tag in which you load the bootstrap js file. then im your webcomponent import the newly created html file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work for me. My 'bootstrap-import.html' file contains:

<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

And then I imported it to 'my-component.html' file:
<link rel="import" href="bootstrap-import.html">

But, dropdown doesn't expand((
Please, maybe you could give some example?

Comment: Bootstrap JS uses Jquery and there seem to be some issues using Jquery with Shadow DOM. Check this
http://robdodson.me/dont-use-jquery-with-shadow-dom/

Answer (score 1):

Use the below, I will attach one sample code below as well :

```
https://github.com/LostInBrittany/granite-bootstrap/blob/master/demo/index.html


<!-- import the module  -->
<link rel="import" href="../granite-bootstrap/granite-bootstrap.html">
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <!-- include the style module by name -->
    <style include="granite-bootstrap"></style>
    <style>:host { display: block; }</style>
    Hi
  </template>
  <script>Polymer({is: 'x-foo'});</script>
</dom-module>
```